# Solr: deltaQuery / parentDeltaQuery / deltaImportQuery

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Solr's documentation for DataImportHandler  gives this table for the entity query attributes.

[image]

That's not extremely descriptive.  Can someone express here the difference and interaction between these query attributes?  I have seen some code use deltaQuery and parentDeltaQuery to support nested entities, and I have seen others use deltaQuery and deltaImportQuery.

What is the purpose of choosing one of those over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see it now in the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example):

```
* The query gives the data needed to populate fields of the Solr document in full-import
* The deltaImportQuery gives the data needed to populate fields when running a delta-import
* The deltaQuery gives the primary keys of the current entity which have changes since the last index time
* The parentDeltaQuery uses the changed rows of the current table (fetched with deltaQuery) to give the changed rows in the parent table. This is necessary because whenever a row in the child table changes, we need to re-generate the document which has that field.
```

I missed this explanation on the first pass, and expected that information to show up in the table I posted.  Strangely enough, **Solr In Action** spent less than 1 page of 600 explaining how to use DataImportHandler to read a database.